# Capture image of uiview underneath top uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Does anyone know how or if its possible to capture an image, guessing bitmap, of the view underneath my current view?

So say you have the top most view as an MKMapView (MyMapview) 320x460, then a popup or another uiview (2ndView)300x300  is shown above the MyMapview. Then a 3rd view (3rdView)320x320 shows up on top of MyMapview and 2ndView.

So you end up with

3rdView 320x320
2ndView 300x300 
MyMapview 320x460

Now what I want to do is capture an image of everything on 2ndView and MyMapview, but only under the frame of 3rdView.

What I am trying to do is recreate the look of iOS7 without requiring users to be on iOS7. This means I want the views underneath to show through, but be blurred. So I figured I would make the 3rdView alpha at .7 but also contain a UIImageView as 3rdViews bottom most layer. Then I take a snapshot of views underneath, blur it, and store in my UIImageView. Now my 3rdViews background is the snapshot of the views underneath but blurred.

Or does someone have a more languaged based way of doing this? I can't create this background image in photoshop and blur it then import it as the bottom most view is a live mkmapview (means I can't snapshot a map of Chicago, blur it and import it as the map might be over Dallas or Paris.

Answer (score 1):

this method will transform a view to an image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

what you can do is remove the top view and then get the image of the view you want and add the top view again.. Hope it works

Comment: Close but I need an image of all view underneath not just one. Or if I need to capture the images separately then how can I composite them into one.

Comment: okay, choose the lower most view you want as the "view". Lets say you have view1 on the bottom, view2, view3 and view4 on top... and you want everything from view1 to view3 in an image. remove view4, and use the lower most view you want (in my case view1) .. so [view1.layer render....], it should take everything on top and put it in an image...